# Possible to get asp.net like upload button in Sharepoint2010 List?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it Possible to get `asp.net like upload button in Sharepoint2010 List?`. On Sharepoint 2010.

I am adding a column to a list. Requirement is that while filling entry in list, one column should have an upload button. This will upload an image to DB.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide more details what are you mainly trying to do?

Please Find Below link it may be helpful to you , you can get your requirement fulfill using Field Control.

http://www.sharepointings.com/creating-a-field-control-for-sharepoint-a-filepicker/